# Search for Hospitals and Clinics near a particular zip code

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to know a method to search for hospitals or clinics within a particular radius around a pin code. How do I go about this and integrate it into my website? I would be using google maps api for the first time so please try and use simple terms.

Okay so I manage to do this much

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var infowindow;
  var geocoder;
  var lat;
  var lng;
  var custom;

  function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address = "Mumbai 400004";
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          custom = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
          map.setCenter(custom);    
        }
      });

        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: custom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var request = {
      location: custom,
      radius: 500,
      types: ['hospital']
    };

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
</script>
```

the problem now is that markers for hospitals are not showing on the map. What mistake have I made here ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Did you take a look at the [Google maps api examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/)

Comment: how can I search using a pincode ?
I should be using the Nearby Search in google maps api right ? 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: Look at the Geocoder class in the Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) to get the geometry of the pincode. You could then use that in the Nearby Search.

Comment: one problem I am facing is that even though the variable custom is global I doesnt seem to hold the value outside the if block. Thus not being passed in the Location attribute of request.